# How to query two fields (different) into one field

Tags: database, nested, field

I'm new here.
I've done a lot of searches and have had a lot of questions answered by existing posts.
I think I'm getting to a point of real complication now, because I am not finding answers as easy anymore.

I'm going to explain my situation as bare/simplified as possible.

So I've got a Master Item Code Table :

```
item
E01
E02
E03
E04
```

And a Sub Item Code table that ties to the Master Item Code (this captures variations/sizes)
It is a one to many relationship with the Master Item code:

```
item    subItem
E02     E02_S
E02     E02_M
E02     E02_L
E03     E03A
E03     E03B
E03     E03C
E04     E04A_S
E04     E04A_M
E04     E04B_L
E04     E04B_XL
```

Note that E01 does not have a subItem as it contains no variation.

I performed a query with join between the two tables to include all item and subitems:

```
SELECT master.item, [Size List].subItem
FROM master Left JOIN [Size List] ON master.[item] = [Size List].[item];

item    subItem
E01 
E02     E02_S
E02     E02_M
E02     E02_L
E03     E03A
E03     E03B
E03     E03C
E04     E04A_S
E04     E04A_M
E04     E04B_L
E04     E04B_XL
```

The list is as expected, with each subitem and master item occupying one row. Note that E02,E03 and E04 plain does not occupy a row when its subitems are available, and E01 occupies a row because no variation exists.

How would I update this query to merge the master and sub to one field so they would still occupy each row the way the join would? In general, I am trying to create a list of unique items, where the subitems act as unique replacing their related master level.

*combinedItemList

```
E01
E02_S
E02_M
E02_L
E03A
E03B
E03C
E04A_S
E04A_M
E04B_L
E04B_XL
```

Any help or insight would be most appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I think you've done a good job describing your question, but you may want to give the [Formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) section of the Help Center a read so you can format your code snippets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first statement gets all the items which doesn't have subitems.

The second statement gets all the sub items where item value exists and combines them.

```
select DISTINCT master.item
from master
left join [Size List]
master.[item] = [Size List].[item]
where [Size List].subItem is  null
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT [Size List].subitem
FROM    [Size List]
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you! I edited the code you provided to the following, but I know what you were getting at! I had no idea a union could just merge two different fields that easily.

```
select DISTINCT master.item
from master 
left join [Size List] 
On master.[item] = [Size List].[item] 
Where [Size List].subItem is  null
Union
SELECT DISTINCT [Size List].subitem
FROM    [Size List]
```